# Applying style to a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-listview, styles

I want each ListView row, has a border
I have a LayerList inside the drawable folder, the name is "border.xml":

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/azulViewPager" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/grisFondoCuadros" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I want to apply this LayerList, like style, to a FrameLayout.
I do it in the following way.
in the file named styles.xml:

```
 <!-- Styles Shadows -->
    <style name="row_border" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/border</item>
    </style>
```

And in the xml of the listview row:

```
<FrameLayout
    style="@style/row_border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

My problem is that the ListView looks and works perfectly, but the style never applied.
I tested many options but without success

I appreciate any help

regards